# Place image over entire section

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to achieve this (using tailwind) : [image]

Currently I have:

```
<section class="bg-juli-white pt-24">
    <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto flex flex-col">
      <h1 class="self-end text-juli-red text-4xl font-bold">meet the team.</h1>
      <img
        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15860716/pexels-photo-15860716.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
        alt=""
        class="w-52 self-end"
      />
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="bg-juli-peach py-10 px-10 w-full h-40">
    <h3 class="text-white font-bold">
      Incididunt laboris labore consequat nisi.
    </h3>
  </section>
```

What would be the most straightforward way to fix this, taking into account that I am heavily using flexbox on this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the overlap by using a negative margin. I'd recommend wrapping the image in a containing div, where you can set the height, width, and margins. Then you can easily set the image to cover the container.

```
<section class="bg-juli-white pt-24">
  <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto flex flex-col items-end">
    <h1 class="text-juli-red text-4xl font-bold">meet the team.</h1>
    <div class="h-80 w-52 -mb-28 mr-16">
      <img 
        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15860716/pexels-photo-15860716.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" 
        alt="" 
        class="h-full object-cover" 
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="bg-juli-peach py-10 px-10 w-full h-40">
  <h3 class="text-white font-bold">
    Incididunt laboris labore consequat nisi.
  </h3>
</section>
```

[codepen example here](https://codepen.io/charcharmasonjar/pen/abRZYev)